# I need the ability to make private listings/custom orders in Magento, how can I?

Tags: custom, listing

I need the ability to create a one of the order for a customer, it would be a customization of a product which is usually in my catalog, but not always.

I need the equivalent of Etsy's custom order feature, where a customer requests, say for example an order for 6 widgets when you normally sell 5, or a product you don't even have in your catalog.

Ideally, I would like to create the custom order and email them a link, then they can go to this one off the page and either add to cart and pay or better yet to a prepopulated "cart-like" screen where they can start the payment there.

**I've looked thru standard features and searched the net, but am not seeing what I need.**

**Any guidance on: Closest I can get out of the box?**

An extension?

This is too specific and needs a hell ton of work?

Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides no default functionality for this out of the box. You can look into using product options to specify different parts of data about the item, but they will not do what you are looking for out of the box.

In terms of custom extensions that provide this functionality, I'm not aware of any. I'm pretty wary to recommend third-party extensions to others without having audited the codebase, because some of them are pretty bad. I recommend searching around, or contacting a Magento development shop if you'd be interested in getting this feature developed. As a warning, I will tell you that what you are thinking of is extremely complex, and could easily run you $5,000+ to have written.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I looked at invoicing, and that side of the system but didn't see that would work either.  Maybe an extension out there that does part of what I need?

Comment: Like I said, I don't know of any off the top of my head, and if I had heard of one, I'd want to audit it first...